# Unable to sum column values on Dataframe / Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 1000 columns and 100 rows (several NaNs). I'm trying to sum all the rows and add them in a column at the end. My script runs smoothly, however I'm not getting the right results (I had to double check random rows manually.

This is the code I'm using

```
df['sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

The results I'm getting by using this are: -5.198331e-11, but when I'm doing it manually (using excel) the result is so different: 4.041211e-13

Comment: These seem like tiny numbers where you're running into precision problems.

Comment: What I worried the most is that some results are positives and other are negatives

Comment: what is the average value of the rows ``df.mean(axis=1)``? if it is not near 0, then  this might just be numerical error.

Comment: How is Excel handling the NaNs? Are they just blank cells?